# How to fix this 'unexpected end of JSON input' bug?

Tags: javascript, json

Just started a 'Writing JS for the Web' course with following exercise and code, but getting 'unexpected end of JSON input' message upon completion of the exercise. Any idea what's going wrong? I'm coding in the following Codepen: https://codepen.io/nicolaspatschkowski/pen/GRJBZjy?editors=1111

```
// Get form elements
const titleInput = document.getElementById('title');
const contentInput = document.getElementById('content');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');

const url = 'https://us-central1-open-classrooms-js-for-the-web.cloudfunctions.net/widgets';

// Get DOM elements for showing response
const responseMessage = document.getElementById('response-message');
const responseTitle = document.getElementById('response-title');
const responseId = document.getElementById('response-id');
const responseContent = document.getElementById('response-content');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', ($event) => {
  $event.preventDefault();
  const post = {
    title: titleInput.value,
    content: contentInput.value
  };
  submitFormData(post);
});

function makeRequest(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', url + '/create-post');
    request.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (request.readyState === 4) {
        if (request.status === 201) {
          resolve(JSON.parse(request.response));
        } else {
          reject(JSON.parse(request.response));
        }
      }
    };
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
}

async function submitFormData(post) {
  try {
const requestPromise = makeRequest(post);
const response = await requestPromise;
responseMessage.textContent = response.message;
responseTitle.textContent = response.post.title;
responseId.textContent = response.post.id;
responseContent.textContent = response.post.content; 
  } catch (errorResponse) { responseMessage.textContent = errorResponse.error;
  }
};
```

Comment: Use the Javascript debugger in your browser to check what `request.response` actually is.

Comment: I tried console.log to check it and it seems to return an empty string...

Comment: That explains the error message. An empty string is no JSON. Are you sure the `/create-post` endpoint returns JSON?

Comment: I think you're right... Maybe it's a server error. The course is a couple of years old too... When I'm checking https://us-central1-open-classrooms-js-for-the-web.cloudfunctions.net/widgets/create-post in the browser it's showing an error too but that must be because doing a get request, right?

Comment: If you type the URL in a browser's address bar, that leads to a GET request, correct.

Comment: The upper directory (without the /create-post endpoint so to say), https://us-central1-open-classrooms-js-for-the-web.cloudfunctions.net/widgets, should return JSON, right? That's giving an error too...

Comment: No, the POST request to the endpoint _with_ `/create-post` should return JSON. That's at least what your code expects.

Comment: You might be running into a dead link - as you say, the course is old, and perhaps the links used are no longer valid. In order to be able to test the functionality of your code, replace the URL which you are currently using with something else. For example, try [this out](https://pokeapi.co/), or [this](https://open-meteo.com/), or [this](https://api.nasa.gov/). Some of these support POST requests, some don't. Experiment and look around until you find an API that works for you.

Comment: Yeah, thanks everybody, it must be the server. I did a console.log of the status code and it's returning 0...